# Pipe Leak in Irrigation Box

Tags: sprinkler-system

I have a leak in my sprinkler/irrigation box. Not sure where to start. Is this something I can easily fix? What steps would be necessary?

Here is a short video of the leak:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/0eznxjozyt44ew7/2018-04-14%2015.24.36.mov?dl=0

Picture of the leak:
[image: 1]]

Comment: Questions; is the water coming from the city at the top of the box in this picture?  Your switch is closed causing water pressure to build up above that valve?  Yes, this is something you can do.  Where is the backflow device that protects your drinking water from possible contamination back flowing from the lawn..?  If this is your main water connection this is a job for the city. Do you have an irrigation company that comes in the fall to blow the water of your system out of the pipes and then comes back in the spring to turn it back on, check valves and heads and leaks?  A service you pay?

Comment: What does the lid of that box say?  I am seeing either city or municipal is responsible to maintain and fix this service or possibly your irrigation winterizing service.  First.  If so you do not want to fix because if you do it wrong it might cost you even more down the road.  Where is the main water supply line that you can turn this water off?  If there is nothing else then this is a call to the city!  Are you being charged for the water coming out of this leak?  That would make this an emergency!

Comment: @stormy - Water is sourcing from the bottom of the box. There's another box near the sidewalk/street (which is the city's box). It has a meter. I've had to turn the water off there using the angle stop (https://www.flower-mound.com/DocumentCenter/Home/View/441
) to make sure I'm not being charged for this water.

The box that is leaking (the one I posted with the pictures) is in the middle of my property and I believe is mine. I was under the impression it controls the sprinklers.  And there is another connection that splits off from the city's main source that is going into my home.

Comment: @stormy We had a hot water underground slab leak earlier in the year. And the guys who repaired it (dug a tunnel under our home) told me that box (I posted with the pictures) was for the sprinklers. They were able to turn it off somehow separately from my main home's water at times when they were testing.

Comment: Glad you are able to turn the water off.  This leak might look minuscule but I've seen the water bills for less.  This is not normally a home owner's responsibility.  Where do you live?  Are you in a development or are you semi rural?   I would keep that water turned off until you absolutely need that water.  Big bucks.  We need to find who the heck is responsible!  Do you have a regular irrigation company that winterizes your irrigation system?  Now is not the time to learn plumbing, grins.  Do you see that lower turn off?  It is halfway turned that I am able to see.  That would take pressure

Comment: More information DaR...where do you live?  Gees, just vague vicinity?  Are you in the states?  Depending on the state and different rules, that contractor looks to be responsible.  States have warranties..Washington has 12 years to keep the contractors and subcontractors under the customer's  thumb.  The contractor has to fix their mistakes at their own cost.

Comment: I live in Texas (DFW area). We bought the home a year and a half ago. It's around 20 years old. I have no background regarding the installation history. Unfortunately I'm pretty sure I'm on the hook for repairs. Looks like I'll be calling in a plumber/sprinkler repairman tomorrow.

Comment: please post pictures directly to the site, since dropbox links will become unavailable after some time.

Comment: Get that leak fixed asap.  Do you remember your expectations when you bought this home regarding the irrigation system?  An irrigation company; look up Angie's List.  Get at least 2 bids and talk to your neighbors before choosing a company.  Eliminate the con artists the best you are able at the very beginning.  Gotta stop that leak so talk to the guy who comes out...learn what you can from him.